# Flutter AppBarTheme Class Constructor Deprecated

Tags: flutter, dart, deprecated

In beginning to learn Flutter cross-platform application development, I am following along Nick Manning's [Flutter Course - Full Tutorial for Beginners (Build iOS and Android Apps)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTJJsmejUOQ). However, at 43:47 of the video, I am getting the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMw6g.png).

Essentially, the App class is the class called by the runApp() method of Main's runApp method. The code in question is the appBarTheme parameter of the ThemeData widget. A constant named AppBarTextStyle is given as the argument for  the TextTheme constructor, which is in turn an argument for AppBarTheme. At the moment, the program would not really achieve any constructive output, but I am trying to set the text theme for the remainder of the program which does not work.

The code for app.dart and style.dart is given below.

```
// app.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screens/location_detail/location_detail.dart';
import 'style.dart';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: LocationDetail(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          textTheme: TextTheme(title: AppBarTextStyle),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const LargeTextSize = 26.0;
const MediumTextSize = 20.0;
const bodytextSize = 16.0;

const String FontNameDefault = "Montserrat";

const AppBarTextStyle = TextStyle(
  fontFamily: FontNameDefault,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
  fontSize: MediumTextSize,
  color: Colors.white,
);
```

After looking at the Flutter [AppBarTheme class API documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBarTheme-class.html), it appears that the constructor for AppBarTheme had been deprecated since the release of the video. This is the deprecation message given in the Flutter documentation:

> @Deprecated('This property is no longer used, please use systemOverlayStyle instead. ' 'This feature was deprecated after v2.4.0-0.0.pre.')

As prompted, I tried replacing the default constructor with the suggested named constructor, systemOverlayStyle. But this was to no avail, as I received the following [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwVnq.png).

I have no idea how to fix my code and would very much appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what are you trying to archive?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first StackOverflow post and I apologize if my post was challenging to follow. I have updated the content of my post with code examples and what I am trying to achieve. Thank you for the feedback and the helpful link!

Comment: Try with `titleTextStyle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change appBar text theme, you need to use `toolbarTextStyle` and `titleTextStyle`.

```dart
theme: ThemeData(
  appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
    toolbarTextStyle: TextStyle(..),
    titleTextStyle: TextStyle(..),
  ),
),
```

It is better with [extending parent theme](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes#extending-the-parent-theme)

> A better rich content is [cookbook/design/themes](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes)

Comment: glad to help you out. Also try to follow official doc instead of video whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like this instead of `textTheme`:

```dart
 MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
          color: darkBlue,
          toolbarTextStyle: const TextTheme(
            headline6: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ).bodyText2,
          titleTextStyle: const TextTheme(
            headline6: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ).headline6,
        ),
      ),
      home: SafeArea(
        child: const Scaffold(
          body: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help! Using Yeasin Sheikh's solution seemed to work convincingly, but I will revisit this suggestion if anything goes wrong again.